# What to do next?

Tags: python, json, sqlite

This application will read roster data in JSON format, parse the file, and then produce an SQLite database that contains a User, Course, and Member table and populate the tables from the data file.

This code is incomplete as I need to modify the program to store the role column in the Member table to complete the problem. And I cannot understand how to do it.

```
import json
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('rosterdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Member;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Course;

CREATE TABLE User (
    id     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Course (
    id     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title  TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Member (
    user_id     INTEGER,
    course_id   INTEGER,
    role        INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, course_id)
)
''')

fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'roster_data.json'

# [
#   [ "Charley", "si110", 1 ],
#   [ "Mea", "si110", 0 ],

str_data = open(fname).read()
json_data = json.loads(str_data)

for entry in json_data:

    name = entry[0];
    title = entry[1];

    print name, title

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO User (name) 
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( name, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM User WHERE name = ? ', (name, ))
    user_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Course (title) 
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( title, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Course WHERE title = ? ', (title, ))
    course_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Member
        (user_id, course_id) VALUES ( ?, ? )''', 
        ( user_id, course_id ) )

    conn.commit()
```

Once the necessary changes are made to the program and it has been run successfully reading the given JSON data, run the following SQL command:

```
SELECT hex(User.name || Course.title || Member.role ) AS X FROM 
    User JOIN Member JOIN Course 
    ON User.id = Member.user_id AND Member.course_id = Course.id
    ORDER BY X
```

Find the first row in the resulting record set and enter the long string that looks like 53656C696E613333.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one hand, there are two changes you need to make in your code:

```
name = entry[0];
title = entry[1];
role = entry[2];

print name, title, role
```

and

```
cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Member
    (user_id, course_id, role) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )''',
    ( user_id, course_id, role ) )
```

but on the other hand, if you're having problems with your Coursera homework, you should really be posting to the class discussion forums about it (after reading what people have already posted about it there, in case that answers your questions) rather than to Stack Overflow. Considering that your question is about an assignment that was due some time ago rather than a current one, I don't feel so bad about talking about it here, but yeah, in the future use the discussion forums instead, and look at what I posted here to understand what is going on.

Comment: thank you :)
i'll take care of it from next time.